# Scrapy FTP export not working

Tags: ftp, export, scrapy

I'm trying to upload the CSV containing all my scraped data on FTP, using

```
scrapy crawl spidername --set FEED_URI=ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/path/to/export.csv
```

The Terminal doesn't give any error and starts scraping, but when it finishes its work I can't see any file on my server.

Additional information:

- Scrapy version 1.0.3
- Operating System Mac OS X El Capitan
- List item

The spider works perfectly if I write to a local file (CSV or Json).

Help?

**UPDATE**
I didn't make anything new, nor changed anything in my code, but after many tries, it worked. The file is on the server. Unfortunately I can't say what made it work this time.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can't see why. There are a lot of other Scrapy related questions here...

Comment: Questions on writing a script in Scrapy are on-topic here. But questions on using command-line scrapy tool are off-topic. As a matter of fact, your question has nothing to do with programming. It has also nothing to do with [tag:python] (the fact that Scrapy is written in python has nothing to do with using the tool from command line).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It seems to me that this is a problem with command line options with `scrapy`. Does that make it less `off-topic`?

Comment: @FrankMartin I do not think so. It's not *"a specific programming problem"* or *"a software algorithm"*, or *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it **is** a specific programming problem. It's related to one of the last steps you can do with Scrapy and it's part of Scrapy. I agree it happens on the Terminal, but I fear if I move my question to Super User, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `global option` of `scrapy` wrong. Help says it should be one of the following formats:

--set=NAME=VALUE, -s NAME=VALUE

So use the `-s` instead of `--set`.

Comment: Hello @Frank Martin and thanks for your answer. I tried `scrapy crawl spidername -s FEED_URI=ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/path/to/export.csv` as you wrote, but the folder in my server is still empty. I'm sure user, password, host and path are correct. I set the folder permissions to 777. I don't know what to do now...

Comment: Maybe you also need to add the `-t csv` option to tell `scrapy` that you'd like to export in that format!? Just guessing as I never did export directly to ftp.

Comment: Ok, added `-t csv`. Doesn't work. Thank you for your help. I'll keep searching for a solution and if I can find something working, I'll post it here.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more info: scrapy version, Operating System, Output of your command. Does your spider work if you write to a local file?

Comment: Done, thank you @Frank Martin. The output doesn't mention any error. It just works as if I'm working with a local file. It does its work but doesn't write to the server.

Comment: Do you have also a line in the terminal output that reads like `[scrapy] INFO: Stored jsonlines feed (30 items) in: ftp://anonymous:guest@test.example.org/incoming/export.csv` ?

Comment: No, I searched for it and the Terminal doesn't output that.

Comment: Lets continue this in chat. Join me at [scrapy chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92157/scrapy)

Comment: Sorry - I did not realize the reputation limit! When I use the `-s FEED_URI=...` I get either a ERROR message or the mentioned INFO message. I'm somehow out of ideas - maybe you can post your problem to the `scrapy-users` mailing list (see scrapy website for reference)!?

Comment: Hello again and thank you for your patience! I re-launched the crawl and at the end the line `INFO: Stored jsonlines feed (1574 items) in: ftp://etc...` appeared. What does that mean?

Comment: My interpretation is that `scrapy` created the file - otherwise there would be an ERROR (try wrong parameters to test that). Can you have a look on the FTP-Server log?

Comment: I updated the question: it worked. I honestly can't say what made it work, considering that I didn't make anything new. I just re-launched the crawler as always.

Comment: Great :-) I'm happy to hear that it finally works. Feel free to accept my answer (if it was useful for you). Greetings from Heidelberg